# Running into a loop due to auth guard

Tags: angular, routes, auth-guard

I am redirecting users to permissible views using routes. But users that do not have permission to a view can route to it by providing the path[route] in the address bar.

I tried using auth-guard, but using it leads me into a continuous loop i.e /[somePath] fires the canActivate and check the permissions and after resolving the route it again get into auth-guard due to canActivate present in all the routes.

Below is the piece of code [what i have tried] -

app.routing.ts

```
{
    path: '',
    component: A,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'B',
    component: B,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'C',
    component: C,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'D',
    component: D,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'E',
    component: E,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

auth-guard.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

if (this.ck.getUser()) {
    // check if route is restricted by role
    if(this.ck.hasRealmRole('A')){
      this.router.navigate(['/A']);
      return false;
    }
    if(this.ck.hasRealmRole('B')){
      this.router.navigate(['/B']);
      return false;
    }
    if(this.ck.hasRealmRole('C')){
      this.router.navigate(['/C']);
      return false;
    }

    if(this.ck.hasRealmRole('D')){
      this.router.navigate(['/D']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}


return false;
```

}

Please help me with how can i restrict an user to navigate to views that are not permitted to them.

Comment: Why are you re-navigating inside `if` blocks, just return true if the condition satisfies

Comment: I think in this scenario, your other routes must be children of the parent route `{path; ' ' .. canActivate: [AUthGuard], children: [ {path: 'B'} ] }`.

Comment: @xyz I need to check if the logged in user have the required permission to navigate to the desired view.